# How to make dynamic bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

for example, i have 3  tag with different target-data each.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#firstdata">
    DATA 1
</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seconddata">
    DATA 2
</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirddata">
    DATA 3
</a>
```

how i can get different id, title, and also content of the modal?i won't create 3 modal, i only use 1 block code of modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="firstdata" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">FIRST DATA</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>FIRST DATA CONTENT</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that is what you looking: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-copy-the-content-of-a-div-into-another-div-using-jquery/, You can use Jquery to get a necessary content and render that in same modal on click, just clean the `modal-body`.

Answer (score 0):

add the below J Query code in your scripts

```
$(document).on('click','.btn-sm',function(){
       
        $("#firstdata").modal();
});
```

Please don't forget to import J query otherwise it will not work

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above code should be above your bootstrap import